# ¿Se utiliza actualmente "guachapear" en alguna de sus acepciones "oficiales"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, hispanoamérica, español-neutral

He oido usar la palabra **guachapear** [o algo que sonaba parecido] con el sentido de "comunicarse a través de Whatsapp". Pensé que era un neologismo creado adaptando al español el nombre del programa y conviertiéndolo en verbo, pero para salir de dudas he consultado los diccionarios y recursos habituales. Para mi sorpresa he encontrado que no solo la palabra **guachapear** existe desde hace siglos, sino que tiene más de una docena de acepciones, unas del español neutral y otras que son americanismos.

Las acepciones que he encontrado son:

[**Diccionario de la Lengua**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jbhd6KT)

> De agua y la onomat. *chap*.
>   1. tr. coloq. Golpear y agitar con los pies el agua detenida. U. t. c. intr.
>   2. tr. coloq. Hacer algo deprisa y chapuceramente.
>   3. intr. Dicho de una chapa de hierro: Sonar por estar mal clavada.

En el [**Diccionario de americanismos**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=guachapear)

> I. 1.  intr. Mx:SE. Bailar la **jarana** con un zapateo vivo.
>   II.    1.  tr. Ve:E. Lavar ligeramente un trapo o una tela cualquiera.
>   III.   1.  tr. Ni. Labrar burdamente la madera.

En otros diccionarios (por medio del [**NTLLE**](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle)):

> - ant. fam. Recrearse bebiendo (Salva 1846)
> - p. us. *Amér* En Chile, **retejar**, 1ª acep. (Alemany y Bolufer 1917:)

Otras acepciones extraídas del [**fichero general**](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html) de la RAE:

> - tr. *Costa, Llanos, Tol.* Cortar o tumbar el rastrojo o maleza de un modo ligero o incompleto. [1975 Ac. Colomb. Breve Dicc. Colomb.]
> - v. a. Nav. Moverse en el agua o hacer caminar una embarcación impeliéndola o nadando con los piés. 1864 Lorenzo-Murga-Ferreiro Dicc.
>     Marit. Esp.]
> - *Tol* Sacudir, zangolotear. [1983 ALARIO DI FILIPPO Lex. colombianismos]
> - En las compras del comercio, engañar al cliente, ya sea por una alteración maliciosa del precio, del peso o tamaño de la mercadería.
> - Garrapatear, escribir descuidadamente.

En el [**Corpus del Nuevo Diccionario Histórico del Español**](http://web.frl.es/CNDHE/org/publico/pages/consulta/entradaCompleja.view) solo aparecen 4 referencias de uso:

- una de 1589 (PINEDA, JUAN DE, Diálogos familiares de la agricultura cristiana),
- dos de 1605 (ambas en LÓPEZ DE ÚBEDA, FRANCISCO, La pícara Justina), y
- una de 1986 (FANER, PAU, Flor de sal : "El guachapeo de cada nueva gota [de agua] era un estruendo descomunal ...).

En el  [**CORDE**](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) tan solo la misma referencia de Juan de Pineda.

En el [**Corpus del Español del Siglo XXI - CORPES XXI**](http://web.frl.es/CORPES/view/inicioExterno.view), un único uso de 2004 (EDWARDS, JORGE: El inútil de la familia: "En el Diccionario de don Zorobabel figura la voz "guachapear", que sería de origen castellano y significaría el ruido que forman, al andar, las herraduras de los animales mal herrados. Entre nosotros ...  significa "hurtar prendas de poco valor: un cortaplumas, un libro, cigarros, volada, etcétera".)

**¿Se sigue utilizando alguna de estas acepciones "oficiales"?**

Comment: Esto es lo que yo llamo una investigación previa, sí señor.

Comment: ¿No habrás escuchado "guasapear"? =p

Comment: @MauricioMartinez: puede ser, en la pregunta ya indico **guachapear [o algo que sonaba parecido]**

Comment: El uso que se da en el último ejemplo (de Jorge Edwards) probablemente está equivocado. La palabra que usamos los chilenos es _guach**i**pear_, con _i_, y significa "hurtar".

Answer (score 1):

La búsqueda en fuentes oficiales y corpus variados ya la hizo OP, así que yo me he centrado en búsquedas más mundanas.

Como casi todos los verbos terminados en *-ear*, el verbo "guachapear" es regular y mantiene la raíz *guachape-* en todas sus conjugaciones.
Por otra parte, Google permite el uso de comodines en las búsquedas. Así, [buscando por "guachape*"](https://www.google.es/search?q=guachape*&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk5L-m2dnYAhVIWhQKHb29ATQQvgUIJSgB&biw=1280&bih=893) podemos encontrar páginas que contengan las palabras: *guachape, guachapear, guachapeo, guachapeando, guachapeéis*...

De estos resultados, muchos (casi todos) son irrelevantes para nuestra consulta:

- usos del nombre "guachape", que según la zona puede referirse a un apellido, a un [río](https://books.google.es/books?id=_blHAQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA341&ots=H5XiaSocyP&dq=guachape%20rio&hl=es&pg=PA342#v=onepage&q=guachape&f=false), a un tipo de [patata](http://www.munisantiagodechuco.gob.pe/Mural/articulo_detalle/37), a una especie de [tortuga](https://es-la.facebook.com/instituto.humboldt/posts/1133150713419150)... pero no es ninguna forma del verbo "guachapear";
- artículos sobre la planta [*Pseudosamanea guachapele* o *Albizia guachapele*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosamanea_guachapele);
- usos de la expresión "guacha pe", de la cual no tengo tiempo para hallar su significado, pero por los usos que he visto tampoco es un verbo.

Google también permite excluir resultados que contengan ciertas palabras. Entonces, si hacemos [otra búsqueda](https://www.google.es/search?biw=1280&bih=893&ei=l3pcWr2OJ8W7UaLbhMAH&q=guachape*%20-pseudomasanae%20-pseudosamanea%20-pseudosamanae%20-albizia%20-guachape%20-guacha&oq=guachape*%20-pseudomasanae%20-pseudosamanea%20-pseudosamanae%20-albizia%20-guachape%20-guacha&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10815.12158.0.14895.8.8.0.0.0.0.94.600.8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.BWm5p7Kds64) excluyendo los resultados que contengan "guachape" (sin sufijos), "pseudosamanea" (junto con ciertas variaciones), "albizia" y "guacha", encontramos...

... nada. Literalmente 0 ocurrencias de formas del verbo "guachapear". Y eso que la búsqueda incluye resultados de Google Books.

Es cierto que, al excluir "guachape" de la búsqueda, hemos eliminado todos los resultados de páginas que versaban sobre la conjugación de dicho verbo. Pero también es cierto que ninguna de esas páginas mostraba usos reales del verbo: casi todas son páginas autogeneradas, en base a la estructura regular del mismo.
La única que se molesta en incluir algún ejemplo es [Jergas de habla hispana](http://www.jergasdehablahispana.org/?pais=Chile&palabra=guachapear&tipobusqueda=1), que ofrece el siguiente uso específico de Chile:

> *Vicente dijo que le **guachapearon** la mochila saliendo de la escuela y por eso no pudo hacer la tarea.*

Su uso sería como sinónimo de *hurtar*. Pero ni siquiera en este caso se cita una fuente: perfectamente podría ser un ejemplo inventado.

**Conclusión: no, no se utiliza actualmente "guachapear" con ninguna de sus acepciones originales.**